# Query for following scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, self-join

I have a table with columns `EMPLOYEEID`, `EMPLOYEENAME`, `MANAGERID`.

`MANGERID` is from the column `EMPLOYEEID`. SOME `EMPLOYEEID` don't have any `manangerid`(i.e. NULL). Now I need a output from query such that it returns `EMPLOYEENAME` and corresponding `MANGERNAME`.

How can It be done?

I have tried  self joins but not able to get desired output.

Comment: Why do you keep adding a `plsql` tag? This is the tag for `PL/SQL` - the procedural SQL language extensions provided by **Oracle** - that has nothing to do with **Microsoft** SQL Server ...

Comment: @marc_s do u write the same query in PL/sql in different ways?is this not useful for oracle guys?

Comment: Do you really need it for Oracle (PL/SQL), too? T-SQL and PL/SQL are **not** the same - there are differences - so if you really need both - let us know. Otherwise, you'll get T-SQL (or PL/SQL) specific solutions....

Comment: i know these are different,but the answer would be useful for both tsql and plsql guys and it will work in both ......thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a self join, with `LEFT JOIN` to get those that has no manager:

```
SELECT
  e.EMPLOYEEID,
  e.EMPLOYEENAME,
  m.EmployeeName AS ManagerName
FROM Employees AS e
LEFT JOIN Employees AS m ON e.ManagerId = m.EmployeeID;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0467a/1)